# Removing Duplicates of an Array in an Array That Has the Possible Sums of a Number

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

## The `sum` Function

### Problem

A beginner JS programmer here.

This question was created out of *curiosity*: I've created a function called `sum` in which takes `value`, a number, as an argument and returns the possible sums of that number, which was stored in variable `a`.

```js
function sum(value) {
  let a = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j <= value; j++) {
      if(i + j === value) {
        a.push([i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Using `sum(5)` returns `[[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 0]]`.

The question is: **is there any way to remove those duplicates?**

Or I want `sum(5)`, for example, to just return `[[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3]]`.

### What I Tried

I tried using a `Set` while using the variable `a` as an array of `i` and `j`, but since objects are unique, the `Set`, `b`, still stored the duplicate, resulting in a `Set` still storing those duplicates.

```js
function sum(value) {
  let a;
  let b = new Set();
  for(let i = 0; i <= value; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j <= value; j++) {
      a = [i, j]; // Forgot that objects are unique in JS.
      b.add(a);
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

I've expected the `Set` to return the possible sums, but as I said, objects are unique in JS, so it still returned the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could remove the duplicates afterwards using some methods, a nicer approach would be to instead iterate only over values that will definitely sum to the target - and to stop once halfway to the target, because after that, you'd be adding duplicates.

```js
function sum(value) {
  const a = [];
  for(let i = 0; i <= value / 2; i++) {
    a.push([i, value - i]);
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(sum(5));
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I never thought of that.